# Uniform local compactness

Tags: general-topology

In course of reading the paper “between Compactness and completeness” I came through the term uniform local compactness, which is not defined in the literature. I couldn’t find it in google. Would some please define the idea of uniform local compactness for me?

Comment: This probably needs more context. Is uniform local compactness a property of a space? If so, then my guess is that you’ve endowed the space with the uniform metric, and the space is locally compact in the topology induced by the metric.

Comment: My guess is that this appears in the context of uniform spaces. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation given in the cited paper (section 2), is that if $X$ is a metric space then define $ν(x) = \sup\{\epsilon > 0: S_\epsilon[x] \text{ is compact}\}$. Then $X$ is uniformly locally compact iff $\inf \{ν(x): x \in X\} > 0$. While the paper claims this is equivalent to some other unstated definition, rather than giving it as a definition, it is a very natural definition for the term "uniformly locally compact": not only is the space locally compact, but there is some global $\epsilon > 0$ such that the closed ball of radius $\epsilon$ around a point is always compact.

Answer (score 0):

This [article from the encyclopaedia of General Topology](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/e07-uniform-spaces-I.pdf) defines it as that $X$ has an entourage $U$ (for its uniformity) such that for all $x$, $U[x]$ is compact.
It also gives $\omega_1$ as an example of a locally compact space which is not uniformly locally compact.